# Change money format from european to united states

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where an SQL-Server is using the european money format (e.g. 1289,00) and our software uses the US money format (e.g. 1289.00). Is there a way to change the SQL-Server money format? So far is giving us some errors when we want to save data that involves money amounts. I have access to the source code but I would prefer not to go down that way and also I have certain privileges in sql-server side.

Any pointers?

Comment: To be honest, I would recommend not using the money data type. Decimals are far more useful and easier to work with. If you need to display something as money for whatever reason, you can just use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213505.aspx).

Comment: SQL Server stores money types (and other numeric types) in binary structures with no notation of formatting. The decimal separator is provided by the client application rendering the data. Although you could convert the value to a string with the desired separator in T-SQL, I suggest you do that in the presentation layer.

Comment: @DanGuzman has a very good point. The real question is why your inserts are failing, because the formatting of decimal values should not be relevant.  Please provide more details of the insert errors.

Comment: @wdosanjos, inserts will fail only if the query is not parameterized or if the currency literal is passed with a comma instead of decimal point.  The SQL standard requires a decimal point.

Comment: The errors I get when debugging are because they are not in the right format.